# Check if domain is a part of URL with PHP

Tags: php

If I have a URL, something like:

`http://www.myDomain.com/page.php?a=1&b&2`

How do check with PHP if a myDomain.com is a part of this URL?

Comment: Can the URL in question appear in the querystring - what if it's escaped?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://php.net/strpos

```
<?php
var_dump(strpos('http://www.myDomain.com/page.php?a=1&b&2', 'myDomain.com'));
?>
```

This should return a numeric value of where the text is in the string. If it is not there, however, it will return FALSE

Comment: Just a note here, while this works it might not be the best or most secure way to do this, depending on what you are using it for.      eg: ' var_dump(strpos('http://www.hacker.com/hack.php?myDomain.com', 'myDomain.com')); ' will return true.

Comment: Agreed. ParseURL, as posted below, is most definitely better.

Answer (score 9):

check [parse_url](http://php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php)

```
<?php
    $url = 'http://username:password@hostname/path?arg=value#anchor';    
    print_r(parse_url($url));    
    echo parse_url($url, PHP_URL_PATH);
    ?>
    The above example will output:
    Array
    (
        [scheme] => http
        [host] => hostname
        [user] => username
        [pass] => password
        [path] => /path
        [query] => arg=value
        [fragment] => anchor
    )
```